# Want to figure out which process (pid) is deleting a file on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, filesystems, zsh, lsof

I have a weird issue where files are being deleted from my /tmp folder, sometimes in as little as 5 minutes from creation. Doesn't appear to be the standard clean-tmps part of the periodic scheduler either, that's the default 3 days of no access or whatever. And I don't restart my machine either, it's on the whole time. I just loop doing `ls -l /tmp/<file>` and after some indeterminate amount of time, usually within minutes, it disappears.

I'm trying to figure out which process is doing the deletion, I have tried fswatch like so:

```
touch /tmp/bar;
fswatch -0 -l 0.1 --event Removed --event Link /tmp/ | xargs -0 -n 1 lsof /tmp/bar
# some time later...
lsof: status error on /private/tmp/bar: No such file or directory
```

Of course, since the file is deleted, the above command won't work (file's gone before `lsof` has a chance to find the pids using it).

Is there a way to see which process is deleting a file?

I'm running MacOSX version 12.5 (21G72), if that matters.

Comment: What's the problem? Is something other than your own process deleting a file that your process created and still has open?

Comment: Why on earth do you care what is being deleted from /tmp?  Its a crap folder for programs to use as they please.  Not a place for you to put stuff.  Is something not working because of these deletions?

Comment: I think this is a completely valid and interesting question as it is. Nobody likes one's files (let them be temporary files or not) deleted and not knowing / understanding which process did this. Haven't experienced something similar on my systems, yet (all Linux).

Comment: I often use /tmp as a working area precisely because the files get deleted after a while; but 'after a while' is usually days of disuse, not 5 minutes after.  This may even be affecting processes that write there. And @mpy is right, if some errant unknown process is deleting files, why would it stop at /tmp?

Comment: That said, I haven't seen it for awhile, after removing the Kolide process my company wanted on my laptop. I remember it's installer not working the first time, so installed it twice; might have been some installer residue.